# How to filter an array of objects and return the array of objects using typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, filter

Hi am wondering if someone can help me in the filtering of an array of objects.
When i do the following, it returns me an array of arrays instead of an array of objects which i need to do a specific display

```
 public ngOnInit(): void {
this.checkboxItems.map(x =>
  x.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe((state: boolean) => {
    const filterOption = Object.keys(x.formControl.parent.controls).find(key => x.formControl.parent.controls[key] === x.formControl);
    console.log('test', state, filterOption);
    if (state && filterOption) {
      this.activatedRoute.data?.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((data: Data) => {
        this.timelineModificationsPerYear = data.verticalTimeline?.verticalTimelineModificationPerYears;
        this.timelineModificationsPerYear = this.timelineModificationsPerYear.map(verticalTimelineModificationPerYear =>
          verticalTimelineModificationPerYear.verticalTimelineModifications?.filter(
            verticalTimelineType => verticalTimelineType.type.toLowerCase() === filterOption
          )
        );

        console.log('filter', this.timelineModificationsPerYear);
      });
    }
  })
);
```

}

[image: original data, an array of objects]
[image: filter data, an array of arrays]

Comment: You are `mapping` it rather filtering. Here you have to look `this.timelineModificationsPerYear.map`

Comment: @gorak i have tried to  this.timelineModificationsPerYear = this.timelineModificationsPerYear.filter(verticalTimelineModificationPerYear =>
              verticalTimelineModificationPerYear.verticalTimelineModifications?.filter(
                verticalTimelineType => verticalTimelineType.type.toLowerCase() === filterOption
              ) but this returns indeed the array of objects but not making real filter based on the condition if type matches the filterOptions. It returns the original objects. Can you help with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues here:

1. You have nested subscriptions. It's better to use higher order mapping operators like `switchMap` to avoid multiple subscriptions.
2. You have subscriptions inside a loop. This again would lead to multiple subscriptions that needs to handled when the component is closed. Here you could use a function like `forkJoin`.
3. The issue at hand, array of arrays. You're mapping the array inside each element to the outer variable. So it leads to array of arrays. Instead of `Array#map` you could use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). It's similar to `map`, except it flattens the inner array so have one single outer array with objects.

Try the following

```js
import { forkJoin, NEVER, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

public ngOnInit(): void {
  forkJoin(this.checkboxItems.map(x =>
    x.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      switchMap((state: boolean) => {
        const filterOption = Object.keys(x.formControl.parent.controls).find(key => x.formControl.parent.controls[key] === x.formControl);
        return (state && filterOption) ? this.activatedRoute.data : NEVER;
      })
    )
  )).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  ).subscribe({
    next: (data: Data) => {
      this.timelineModificationsPerYear = data.verticalTimeline?.verticalTimelineModificationPerYears;
      this.timelineModificationsPerYear = this.timelineModificationsPerYear.flatMap(verticalTimelineModificationPerYear => 
        verticalTimelineModificationPerYear.verticalTimelineModifications?.filter(verticalTimeline => 
          verticalTimelineType.type.toLowerCase() === filterOption
        )
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @Micheal D, when using flatMap, is indeed doing the filtering however am losing the structure of the original data structure verticalTimelineModifications  key and year key and . Is there a way to keep the original structure of the objects and apply the filtering condition